# How To Select By Attribute Within Perticular section/div through htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

So I m using Htmlagilitypack on server side to parse html in C#.
Here's a Question..
i have 2 div elements

```
<div>
<a data-clear="movies-something"></a>
<p data-clear="movies-something"></p>
</div>

<div>
<a data-clear="music-something"></a>
<p data-clear="music-something"></p>
</div>
```

i am looping through the div elements and want to find specific data-clear attributes for that. problem is when i am selecting nodes using

```
var cols = fdm.SelectNodes("//@data-clear");
```

on second case i am finding 4 instead of 2 columns..

how to select within only currently looping through div

Comment: its not duplicate i want my list within specific tags

Comment: It is a duplicate. XPATH expression that return attribute nodes are not supported (because Html Agility Pack simple does not define an attribute as being a node, unlike the XML equivalent)

Comment: so duplicate link has question like : I'm trying to retrieve a specific image from a html document,                                   my question is :  i don't want specific images i want things from perticular section in this case Div..

Answer (score 0):

Change your XPATH expression on follows

```
var cols = fdm.SelectNodes("//div[1]//@data-clear");
```

Comment: You're 100% right for XPATH in general, but the Html Agility Pack XPATH implementation doesn't support selecting on attributes. Check the links in my comment.

Comment: It was in 2009. Now HtmlAgilityPack supports selection by attributes. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: Nope. You're confusing this kind of expression `/element[@att]` with this `/@att`. The latter was never supported.

Comment: assume this is true but can we do something like this  fdm.SelectNodes("//div["+index+"]//@data-clear"); or can we??

Comment: Please read the possible duplicate. This XPATH expression is *not possible* with Html Agility Pack.